# react router get full current path name

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there an easy way to return the current router address.

IE, if I'm on page, and I just want to see what page I'm on according to the react router.

So, localhost/admin/users would return admin/users

Obviously, I can get the same results by parsing the location, but I was wondering if react router provides a simple mechanism to do this, the same way it provides the params props?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read the current full URL with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823681/read-the-current-full-url-with-react)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you're using 1.0 or newer, you have the `location` as a prop in your React components that are matched against a route. So you just type

```
this.props.location.pathname
```

to get what you wanted.

Comment: this does not include query parameters

Comment: doesn't include the domain, either

Answer (score 26):

`this.props.location.pathname` gives only the routing path.

`window.location.href` gives you the full URL, as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39823749/7560899

Comment: window is undefined.

Answer (score 19):

For React Functional Component

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = () => {
  let location = useLocation();
  ...useState

    useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location.pathname);
  }, []);

  return ();

  };

  export default MyComponent;
```

There are many other options:
https://dev.to/finallynero/hooks-introduced-in-react-router-v5-1-7g8

Answer (score 11):

You can also try

```
location.pathname
```

It may work while other methods don't as it did to me

Comment: It has nothing to do with react-router. It's browser's window object property.

Comment: Yes, it is. But in some cases it works while the other solution doesn't.

Comment: As a practice, I wouldn't mix browser capabilities with React, since you might use the same code for server side render

Answer (score 10):

For a non-react, pure javascript based solution using the browser window object.
Let's say the current page URL is something like this `https://hostname:port/path?query`.

---

```
window.location.href // returns the full URL 'https://hostname:port/path?query'
```

---

```
window.location.pathname // returns just the 'path' part of the full URL.
```

---

```
window.location.search // returns just the '?query' part of the full URL.
```

---

```
window.location.port // returns the 'port'.
```

---

```
window.location.hostname // returns just the 'hostname' part of the URL.
```

---

```
window.location.host // returns the hostname and port (hostname:port) part of the URL.
```

---

```
window.location.protocol // returns the protocol (https)
```

---

```
window.location.origin // returns the base URL (https://hostname:port)
```

---

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location for more details.

Answer (score 5):

for **react-router-dom v6**

```
const { pathname } = useLocation();
```

import if somebody need it

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.location` will give the full path.

`this.props.location.pathname` - it may not give the full path. use this, if you want just the URL path without the domain prefix. (also, I may suggest using context API to get this in any child components instead of passing this as props)

one more example, to implement the new component with social share feature, you may need to use the `window.location` and not the `location.pathname`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want pathname without / then use it

**`window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]`**