# Read the current full URL with React?

Tags: reactjs

How do I get the full URL from within a ReactJS component?

I'm thinking it should be something like `this.props.location` but it is `undefined`

Answer (score 468, accepted):

`window.location.href` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Please note that it may have problems on server side, if not configured properly.

Comment: I needed window.location for a feature that is client side. So I set the location in the state of my component onMount in order to avoid issues while rendering on server side.

Comment: it is not working. or kindly help me with structure of that in react.

I used 

**const ddd = window.location.href;
console.log(ddd);**

Comment: webpack will complain about this saying 'window is not defined'

Comment: @FranzSee yes there is no "window" in server-side code, so if that's your environment you'll need to use something like `req.originalUrl` from express or whatnot. The various react routing libraries that have SSR support have methods for getting this information.

Comment: This is not the react way to do this.  This is a workaround

Answer (score 180):

If you need the full path of your URL, you can use vanilla Javascript:

`window.location.href`

To get just the path (minus domain name), you can use:

`window.location.pathname`

```js
console.log(window.location.pathname); //yields: "/js" (where snippets run)
console.log(window.location.href);     //yields: "https://stacksnippets.net/js"
```

Source: [Location pathname Property - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp)

If you are not already using "react-router" you can install it using:

`yarn add react-router`

then in a React.Component within a "Route", you can call:

`this.props.location.pathname`

This returns the path, not including the domain name.

Thanks @abdulla-zulqarnain!

Comment: you can do just like that for pathname `window.location.pathname`

Answer (score 68):

`window.location.href` is what you need. But also if you are using react router you might find useful checking out **useLocation** and **useHistory** hooks.
Both create an object with a pathname attribute you can read and are useful for a bunch of other stuff. [Here's a youtube video explaining react router hooks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZeulkp1ClA)

Both will give you what you need (without the domain name):

```
import { useHistory ,useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const location = useLocation()
location.pathname

const history = useHistory()
history.location.pathname
```

Comment: The question already said "with React", apparently `window.location.href` is not the React way.

Comment: this gives me an error, useHistory not found in react-router-dom

Comment: @johnk you are apperantly on react-router-dom version 6. useHistory no longer available with version 6. Checkout useNavigate
https://stackoverflow.com/users/396483/john-k

Answer (score 49):

[`this.props.location` is a react-router feature](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location), you'll have to install if you want to use it.

Note: doesn't return the full url.

Comment: Note: this does not return the full url (host name, protocol, etc.)

Answer (score 26):

Plain JS :

```
window.location.href // Returns full path, with domain name
window.location.origin // returns window domain url Ex : "https://stackoverflow.com"
window.location.pathname // returns relative path, without domain name
```

Using react-router

```
this.props.location.pathname // returns relative path, without domain name
```

Using react Hook

```
const location = useLocation(); // React Hook
console.log(location.pathname); // returns relative path, without domain name
```

Comment: The URL is being asked for here, not just the path. The URL also includes query string and hash.

Comment: about useLocation actually it is quite dangerous advice - useLocation will trigger render if  a location will be changed see docs https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location

Answer (score 15):

You are getting `undefined` because you probably have the components outside React Router.

Remember that you need to make sure that the component from which you are calling `this.props.location` is inside a `<Route />` component such as this:

`<Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />`

Then inside the Dashboard component, you have access to `this.props.location`...

Comment: And if your component is not inside a `<Route />` you can use [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) higher-order component.

Answer (score 11):

Just to add a little further documentation to this page - I have been struggling with this problem for a while.

As said above, the easiest way to get the URL is via `window.location.href`.

we can then extract parts of the URL through vanilla Javascript by using `let urlElements = window.location.href.split('/')`

We would then `console.log(urlElements)` to see the Array of elements produced by calling .split() on the URL.

Once you have found which index in the array you want to access, you can then assigned this to a variable

```
let urlElelement = (urlElements[0])
```

And now you can use the value of urlElement, which will be the specific part of your URL, wherever you want.

Answer (score 9):

Read this I found the solution of `React / NextJs`. Because if we use directly used the `window.location.href` in react or nextjs it throw error like

> Server Error
> ReferenceError: window is not defined

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const Product = ({ product }) => {
 const [pageURL, setPageURL] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setPageURL(window.location.href);
  })
  return (
     <div>
       <h3>{pageURL}</h3>
      </div>
  );
};
```

***Note:***
[https://medium.com/frontend-digest/why-is-window-not-defined-in-nextjs-44daf7b4604e#:~:text=NextJS%20is%20a%20framework%20that,is%20not%20run%20in%20NodeJS](https://medium.com/frontend-digest/why-is-window-not-defined-in-nextjs-44daf7b4604e#:%7E:text=NextJS%20is%20a%20framework%20that,is%20not%20run%20in%20NodeJS).

Answer (score 8):

To get the **current router instance** or **current location** you have to create a Higher order component with `withRouter`  from `react-router-dom`. otherwise, when you are trying to access `this.props.location` it will return  `undefined`

Example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class className extends Component {

      render(){
           return(
                ....
                  )
              }
}

export default withRouter(className)
```

Answer (score 1):

As somebody else mentioned, first you need `react-router` package. But `location` object that it provides you with contains parsed url.

But if you want full url badly without accessing global variables, I believe the fastest way to do that would be

```
...

const getA = memoize(() => document.createElement('a'));
const getCleanA = () => Object.assign(getA(), { href: '' });

const MyComponent = ({ location }) => {
  const { href } = Object.assign(getCleanA(), location);

  ...
```

`href` is the one containing a full url.

For `memoize` I usually use `lodash`, it's implemented that way mostly to avoid creating new element without necessity.

P.S.: Of course is you're not restricted by ancient browsers you might want to try `new URL()` thing, but basically entire situation is more or less pointless, because you access global variable in one or another way. So why not to use `window.location.href` instead?