# apply css to div corresponding to url path in navbar

Tags: css, reactjs

I'd like to make a side menu that shows the user what nav item and accessorarily URL path he's currently on (the Menu items allow you to navigate to say /help or  /legal or /main or / )

[image: menu]

but say a user navigates to /help by entering it in the adress bar how in Reactjs would I change the highlighted menu item.

Keep in mind that the menu state is not reset by navigating these are dynamic pages.

Comment: What are you using for routing?

Comment: Your question contains code that isn't relevant. Please [edit] to add meaningful code that shows what you have tried so far that we can provide you with an accurate answer. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to know what page I'm on I'll do the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick :

```
window.location.href
```

as found in : [Read the current full URL with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823681/read-the-current-full-url-with-react)