# Using React Router to determine ReactApp URL Search

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Lets say I have a serverless website.
MyWebSite.com

If a user types
MyWebSite.com/randomString

How can I capture this extra random information.

The Goal is to Dynamically Display Content based on users Random Url Search

## Investigating This Question

[Read the current full URL with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823681/read-the-current-full-url-with-react)

Comment: you want like youtube search right?

Comment: Sure basically I want to setState a variable based on that randomString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **`react-router-dom`** instead of **`react-router`**

Ok hopefully your route is like `<Route path="/:id" component={Search} />`, in this case you can get the randomString like follows

in functional component:

```
props.match.params.id
```

or in class component:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

Comment: I'm going to try this, instead of the answer I posted, because with my method App component has to mount first and then you have to change a state variable and then you have to call on a component to mount.  Seems like with react-router-dom the component renders based on the URL path automatically.

Answer (score 1):

After Reading the previous question I found this to works just fine.

```
 componentDidMount() {
        console.log(window.location.href);

      }
```