# Get URL in React with Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to get parameters in a hooks component, what's the cleanest way without using react-routes?
Is windows.location.search enough? How to use it in a clean way with hooks?

Comment: Hey Marianne. You don't need to do anything special in the "hook" context - any Javascript code can run in it. The answers in this question will work in any hook you create - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823681/read-the-current-full-url-with-react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read the current full URL with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823681/read-the-current-full-url-with-react)

Comment: Thank you guys, I was wondering if it's considered bad practice writing window element in react directly, or it's just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It has less to do with react if you don't want to use React Router:

```
let paramsString = window.location.search
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString) 
searchParams.has("somequery"); // true if it is present
```

To parse the search params, you can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Comment: I was able to read on https://developer.mozilla.org/ as well alone, my question is about how to use a clean way with hooks.