# Getting Data from custom URL from express server using React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am learning react and express and I was trying to make a simple blog website with React as my Front end and Express server for the backend.

For the Express Server this is my code:-(**app.js**)

```
const express=require('express');
var _ = require('lodash');
const app=express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/client/public/index.html");
});

app.get("/api",function(req,res){
    res.send({heading: "'Hello World"});
});

app.get("/posts/:postName",function(req,res){  //---->want to get data linked with the 'postName'
    let post=req.params.postName;
    console.log(post);
    res.json({postName:post});
});



app.listen(8080,function(){
    console.log("Server is running...");
});
```

And this is something I was able to create by using online sources for React:-(**App.jsx**)

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
```

How should I pass the postname typed in url in the below code?For example I type 'localhost:3000/posts/day1' so that I can find info about post named day1 and render that blog post

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
      fetch("/posts/")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => setData(data.users));
    }, []);
  
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <p>{!data ? "Loading..." : data}</p>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
  

export default App;
```

I hope I am not approaching it in a wrong way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read the current full URL with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823681/read-the-current-full-url-with-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is to make use of React Router.
This official [code example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params) is enough to get you going with it.