# document.location.pathname updating when routing from class component to functional component in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-hooks

These are the routes:

```
const routes = [
    { url: "", component: Home }, //class
    { url: "doctors", component: Doctors }, //class
    { url: "activedevices", component: ActiveDevices }, //functional
    { url: "nurses", component: Nurse }, //functional
    { url: "patients", component: PatientTable }, //functional
    { url: "floor-management", component: FloorManagement }, //class
    { url: "organizations", component: Organizations }, //functional
]

              <Switch>
                {routes.map((data, i) => (
                  <Route
                    key={i}
                    exact
                    path={`/${data.url}`}
                    component={data.component}
                  />
                ))}
                <Route path="*" component={()=> <Redirect to='/' />} />
              </Switch>
```

I'm using window.location.pathname to determine the current path and highlight the corresponding menu item.

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svnSw.png)

[Patients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPdHA.png)

[Floor Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CnRI.png)

It is working fine when I try to navigate between class to class component or class to functional component. But when I try functional to functional component, the window.document.pathname does not update which results in respective menu item not being highlighted and last one remain highlighed. But the routing still works, I'm routed to the clicked routes and it also shows updated route in the address bar but not inside the script.

These are images showing updates routes in address bar but not in pathname:

[Nurses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vk7s.png)

[Active Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkPgp.png)

Here is the code for a functional component:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Table, Pagination, Badge, Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";


import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ActiveDevicesRow from "./ActiveDeviceRow";

import {baseURL, API, BEARER_TOKEN} from '../../../config'


const ActiveDevices = () => {

   const [activeDevices, setActiveDevices] = useState(null)
   let serial=1;

   var myHeaders = new Headers();
   myHeaders.append("Authorization", BEARER_TOKEN);

   var requestOptions = {
     method: 'GET',
     headers: myHeaders,
     redirect: 'follow'
   };

   async function getActiveDevices(){
      await fetch(baseURL+API.DEVICES, requestOptions)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
         if(Array.isArray(res)) setActiveDevices(res)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))

      // console.log(activeDevices)
   }

   useEffect(()=>{
      getActiveDevices()
   }, [])

   const [data, setData] = useState(
      document.querySelectorAll("#ActiveDevices_basic_table tbody tr")
   );
   
   const sort = 5;
   const activePag = useRef(0);
   const [test, settest] = useState(0);

   // Active data
   const chageData = (frist, sec) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
         if (i >= frist && i < sec) {
            data[i].classList.remove("d-none");
         } else {
            data[i].classList.add("d-none");
         }
      }
   };
   // use effect
   useEffect(() => {
      setData(document.querySelectorAll("#ActiveDevices_basic_table tbody tr"));
   }, [test]);

   // Active pagginarion
   activePag.current === 0 && chageData(0, sort);
   // paggination
   let paggination = Array(Math.ceil(data.length / sort))
      .fill()
      .map((_, i) => i + 1);

   // Active paggination & chage data
   const onClick = (i) => {
      activePag.current = i;
      chageData(activePag.current * sort, (activePag.current + 1) * sort);
      settest(i);
   };
   // console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".sorting_1 input")[0].checked);

   return (
      <div className="col-12">
         <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
               <h4 className="card-title">Active Devices</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
               <Table responsive className="w-100">
                  <div
                     id="ActiveDevices_basic_table"
                     className="dataTables_wrapper"
                  >
                     <table
                        id="example5"
                        className="display dataTable no-footer w-100"
                        style={{ minWidth: 845 }}
                        role="grid"
                        aria-describedby="example5_info"
                     >
                        <thead>
                           <tr role="row">
                              <th
                                 className="sorting"
                                 tabIndex={0}
                                 aria-controls="example5"
                                 rowSpan={1}
                                 colSpan={1}
                                 aria-label="Patient ID: activate to sort column ascending"
                                 style={{ width: 73 }}
                              >
                                 S.R. No.
                              </th>
                              <th
                                 className="sorting"
                                 tabIndex={0}
                                 aria-controls="example5"
                                 rowSpan={1}
                                 colSpan={1}
                                 aria-label="Date Check in: activate to sort column ascending"
                                 style={{ width: 100 }}
                              >
                                 ID
                              </th>
                              <th
                                 className="sorting"
                                 tabIndex={0}
                                 aria-controls="example5"
                                 rowSpan={1}
                                 colSpan={1}
                                 aria-label="Patient Name: activate to sort column ascending"
                                 style={{ width: 100 }}
                              >
                                 Name
                              </th>
                              <th
                                 className="sorting"
                                 tabIndex={0}
                                 aria-controls="example5"
                                 rowSpan={1}
                                 colSpan={1}
                                 aria-label="Doctor Assgined: activate to sort column ascending"
                                 style={{ width: 120 }}
                              >
                                 Serial
                              </th>
                              <th
                                 className="sorting"
                                 tabIndex={0}
                                 aria-controls="example5"
                                 rowSpan={1}
                                 colSpan={1}
                                 aria-label="Disease: activate to sort column ascending"
                                 style={{ width: 62 }}
                              >
                                 DeviceType
                              </th>

                              <th
                                 className="sorting"
                                 tabIndex={0}
                                 aria-controls="example5"
                                 rowSpan={1}
                                 colSpan={1}
                                 aria-label="Action: activate to sort column ascending"
                                 style={{ width: 47 }}
                              >
                                 State
                              </th>
                           </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           {activeDevices && activeDevices.length !== 0 ? activeDevices.map((device, index)=>
                                 <ActiveDevicesRow 
                                 key={'device'+device.id}
                                 srNo={serial++}
                                 id={device.id}
                                 serial={device.serial}
                                 name={device.name}
                                 deviceStatus={device.isActive}
                                 deviceType={device.deviceType}
                                 onClick=""
                              />
                           )
                           : <tr><td colSpan='7' style={{textAlign:'center'}}>No Data Available</td></tr>

                        }
                        </tbody>
                     </table>

                     <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mt-3">
                        <div className="dataTables_info">
                           Showing {activePag.current * sort + 1} to{" "}
                           {data.length > (activePag.current + 1) * sort
                              ? (activePag.current + 1) * sort
                              : data.length}{" "}
                           of {data.length} entries
                        </div>
                        <div
                           className="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers"
                           id="example5_paginate"
                        >
                           <Link
                              className="paginate_button previous disabled"
                              to="#"
                              onClick={() =>
                                 activePag.current > 0 &&
                                 onClick(activePag.current - 1)
                              }
                           >
                              Previous
                           </Link>
                           <span>
                              {paggination.map((number, i) => (
                                 <Link
                                    key={i}
                                    to="#"
                                    className={`paginate_button  ${
                                       activePag.current === i ? "current" : ""
                                    } ${i > 0 ? "ml-1" : ""}`}
                                    onClick={() => onClick(i)}
                                 >
                                    {number}
                                 </Link>
                              ))}
                           </span>
                           <Link
                              className="paginate_button next"
                              to="#"
                              onClick={() =>
                                 activePag.current + 1 < paggination.length &&
                                 onClick(activePag.current + 1)
                              }
                           >
                              Next
                           </Link>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </Table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   );
};

export default ActiveDevices;
```

And here is the code for a class component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import DoctorsAccordion from "./DoctorsAccordion";

class Doctors extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    document.title = "Active Doctors"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="form-head d-flex mb-3 mb-lg-5 align-items-start">
          <Link onClick={this.onClick} className="btn btn-danger">
            + New Doctor
          </Link>
          <div className="input-group search-area ml-auto d-inline-flex">
            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search here" />
            <div className="input-group-append">
              <span className="input-group-text c-pointer">
                <i className="flaticon-381-search-2"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Dropdown className="ml-3">
            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="outline-primary" id="dropdown-basic">
              <i className="flaticon-381-controls-3 "></i> Filter
            </Dropdown.Toggle>

            <Dropdown.Menu className="dropdown-menu-right">
              <Dropdown.Item href="#">A To Z List</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item href="#">Z To A List</Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
          </Dropdown>
          <Dropdown className="ml-3">
            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="outline-primary" id="dropdown-basic">
              Newest
            </Dropdown.Toggle>

            <Dropdown.Menu className="dropdown-menu-right">
              <Dropdown.Item href="#">Newest</Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item href="#">Old</Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
          </Dropdown>
          <Link onClick={this.onClick} className="btn btn-outline-primary ml-3">
            <i className="flaticon-381-menu-1 mr-0"></i>
          </Link>
         
        </div>

        <DoctorsAccordion />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Doctors;
```

Here is a screenshot showing functional compoenent path being updated in address bar but no getting logged on console:

[Screenshot of functional comp path not logged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxdTW.png)

Comment: What is `this.onClick` on the `Link` components doing in `Doctor` and why aren't you using the `to` prop? There should be no difference between whether the components being rendered on the Routes or how the routes are navigated to/from. I suspect you are just doing some weird things with navigation. Why look at `window.location.pathname` when the `Router` provides a `location` object? You are linking to "#" instead of defined routes. Etc...

Answer (score 0):

why can't you use `

> `props.location.pathname`insted of
> `window.location.pathname`
> to determine the current path and refer this link [Read the current full URL with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823681/read-the-current-full-url-with-react)