# What is the React Native code for capturing the URL in the browser's tab outside the app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do I automatically catch (get or grab) the clicked URL outside the app in React Native without having to manually copying it from the browser's tab and then pasting it in the code?

Comment: try this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823681/read-the-current-full-url-with-react

if you want the current browser url. its a window property, nothing to do with react specifically

Comment: Noted. Will try it out.

Comment: @MattPengelly I'm new to React Native and want I want is to open a link within the app and then if a certain button is clicked on that external link, I want to capture the URL of that same page where there's a button. 

For example, an Amazon.com website is opened within the app and if an "Add to cart" button is clicked, I want to capture the URL of that same page where there's that button. Please help me with code to do this